# Не обновляется отображение ListCell при обновлении элемента ObservableList в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

В рамках упражнения "TODO List" создаю такой редактируемых карточек:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент до создания новых тасков пока не дошёл, но уже реализовал перенос данных в поля ввода при клике на карточку. Метод сохранения обновленного таска тоже реализовал, но список не обновляется.

```java
public class TaskEditorController {

  private static TaskEditorController selfSoleInstance;

  @FXML private TextField taskTitleTextField;
  @FXML private TextArea taskNoteTextArea;
  @FXML private Button saveChangesButton;

  private ObservableTask targetTask;


  public static TaskEditorController getInstance() {
    return TaskEditorController.selfSoleInstance;
  }

  @FXML
  private void initialize() {
    TaskEditorController.selfSoleInstance = this;
  }


  public void beginTaskEditing(ObservableTask targetTask) {
    this.targetTask = targetTask;
    this.taskTitleTextField.setText(targetTask.getTitle().getValue());
    this.taskNoteTextArea.setText(targetTask.getNote().getValue());
  }

  @FXML
  public void saveEditedTask() {

    this.targetTask.setTitle(this.taskTitleTextField.getText());
    this.targetTask.setNote(this.taskNoteTextArea.getText());

    // Тут всё нормально - проверил что новые данные подбираются.
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    System.out.println(this.taskTitleTextField.getText());
    System.out.println(this.taskNoteTextArea.getText());
    System.out.println(this.targetTask.getTitle().getValue());
    System.out.println(this.targetTask.getNote().getValue());
  }
}
```

Инициализация коллекции тасков происходит следующим образом:

```
public class TasksListController {

  
  /* --- Data ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  private static TasksGateway tasksGateway;


  /* --- GUI Elements ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  @FXML private ListView<ObservableTask> tasksListView;


  @FXML
  private void initialize() {

    ObservableList<ObservableTask> observableTasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Task> pair: TasksListController.tasksGateway.getAll().entrySet()) {
      observableTasks.add(new ObservableTask(pair.getValue()));
    }

    this.tasksListView.setCellFactory(list -> new TaskCard());
    this.tasksListView.setItems(observableTasks);

    this.tasksListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
        (observable, oldValue, newValue)-> this.onSelectTask(newValue)
    );
  }


  private void onSelectTask(ObservableTask targetTask) {
    TaskEditorController.getInstance().beginTaskEditing(targetTask);
  }
}
```

Что я упустил?

### Дополнительно: об обмене данными с формой ввода

Это не по теме, но если Вам не понравилась строка `TaskEditorController.getInstance().beginTaskEditing(targetTask);`, то я её объясню.

На данный момент я не знаю, как в JavaFX организован обмен данными между компонентами произвольного взаимного расположения. Из веб-разработки я знаю, что в таких фреймворках, как Vue, обмен данными может осуществляться посредством:

- Свойств компонента (им может быть и функция)
- Генераторов (эмиттеров) событий
- Продвинутый вариант - единая шина событий типа Vuex

Как обычно делают в JavaFX - мне пока неизвестно, но я попробовал получить инстанс контроллера формы ввода через статический метод `getInstance`. Перенос данных в форму работает, но является ли это причиной возникшей проблемы - не знаю.

### Дополнительно: листинг ObservableTask

Согласной **Чистой Архитектуре**, бизнес-правила не должны зависеть ни от каких фреймворков, потому `ObservableTask` - это обёртка для простой сущности `Task`. Вопросы синхронизации изменений инстансов `ObservableTask` и советующих им простых сущностей `Task` мы здесь пока рассматривать не будем.

```java
public class ObservableTask {

  private StringProperty title;
  private StringProperty note;
  private BooleanProperty isDone;


  public ObservableTask(Task task) {

    this.title = new SimpleStringProperty(task.getTitle());
    this.note = new SimpleStringProperty(task.getNote());
    this.isDone = new SimpleBooleanProperty(task.getIsDone());
  }


  public ObservableTask(Task.RequiredParameters requiredParameters) {
    this.title = new SimpleStringProperty(requiredParameters.title());
  }


  public StringProperty getTitle() {
    return this.title;
  }
  public void setTitle(String newTitle) {
    this.title.set(newTitle);
  }

  public StringProperty getNote() {
    return this.note;
  }
  public void setNote(String newNote) {
    this.note.set(newNote);
  }

  public BooleanProperty getIsDone() {
    return this.isDone;
  }
}
```

Comment: Как один из вариантов - очистить `list view` с задачами при сохранении и потом опять его наполнить. 
Есть еще вариант это сделать все поля ваших тасков в виде пропертей, к которым можно навесить слушателей.

Comment: @Tsyklop, благодарю Вас за ответ! Подскажите пожалуйста, а какова причина по которой на данный момент обновления данных не происходит? Я ожидал, что как только мы сменим свойство элемента коллекции, то и отображение обновится, а если этого не должно быть, то смысл тогда в StringProperty?

Comment: Так происходит ибо слушатели сделаны только на изменение списка записей самих - ObservableList. Что бы происходило изменение нужно что явно сказать об этом списку - StringProperty или SimpleObjectProperty.

Comment: @Tsyklop "вариант это сделать все поля ваших тасков в виде пропертей" - если Вы имеете ввиду `StringProperty`, то это у меня имеется. Добавил листинг `ObservableClass`  в конце вопроса. Насчёт необходимости добавления слушателей на каждое свойство - раз Вы профессионал, значит говорите правильно, но мне перед тем как пробовать Ваше решение нужно понять, что я буду делать. На данный момент мне не понятно, зачем нужно ещё добавлять слушатели и даже если добавлю - то что нужно делать в обработчиках? В следующем комментарии я представлю ход своих мыслей.

Comment: @Tsyklop Из строки `System.out.println(this.targetTask.getTitle().getValue());`) в первом листинге я знаю, что изменение свойство и инстанса `targetTask` прошло успешно. Теперь я ожидаю, что карточка с таском автоматически обновится. Этого не происходит. Я не знаю почему, но из Ваших комментариев я так понял, что и не должно происходить. Отсюда возникает вопрос: что нам даёт `StringProperty` по сравнению с просто `String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В методе Presenter.Components.TasksList.TasksListController.TaskCard#updateItem вместо простого переноса значения

```java
this.titleLabel.setText(observableTask.getTitle().getValue())
```

используйте связывание:

```java
titleLabel.textProperty().bind(observableTask.getTitle())
```

Тогда при обновлении ObservableTask#title будет обновляться и карточка.
Аналогичное связывание нужно сделать и для ObservableTask#note.

Comment: Всё прекрасно заработало! Спасибо Вам за лаконичное решение!